# get_browser not working with IF statement in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

my site uses a new API GetUserMedia() found in the HTML5 standardization. Currently Chrome and Firefox support this API and for the time being I would like to use this API only when a user is using Chrome or Firefox.

The code below demonstrates this API which works great. The problem however is my if statements do not work and when I visit the website using Safari it still tries to activate the API when in fact it should just use the fall back `<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">`

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser["browser"]; //to see which browser name is detected

if ($browser["browser"] = "Chrome" || $browser["browser"] = "Firefox"){
    echo '<script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/webcam.js" charset="utf-8"></script>';
    echo '<video id="video" width="300" height="300" autoplay></video><br>';
    echo '<button id="snap">Capture</button><br>';
    echo '<button id="upload">Upload</button><br>';
    echo '<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="150"></canvas>';

}
if ($browser["browser"] = "Safari" || $browser["browser"] = "IE"){
    echo '<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is not comparision but assignment operator.

should be

```
if ($browser["browser"] == "Chrome"
```

instead of

```
if ($browser["browser"] = "Chrome"
```

It's good practice to find the feature not browser.